# How to get a specific string from the text in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an input and the textarea. What I need to do is when I'm entering a value into input, textarea's specific value would change (I have just only text).

I'm trying to solve it by using `.keyup()` function, but I've no idea if I can somehow take the specific string from a text in jQuery.

Is it possible to do so? How?

For example:

I have a text `This is a percentage`. I have an input and when I'm entering an information into it, the word `percentage` would change on `keydown` or `keyup`.

Comment: share ur work or what you have tried

Comment: What do you mean by specific string? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working example:**

```js
var stringToBeReplaced = "percentage";

$("input").keyup(function(){

   var str = $("#textarea").val().replace(stringToBeReplaced, $(this).val());
   
    $("#textarea").val(str);
    stringToBeReplaced = $(this).val();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id='a'/>
<br>

<textarea id='textarea'>This is a percentage</textarea>
```

Comment: This has a bug. Try typing something in the input then delete everything and start typing again.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do if user leave empty input field. You can set "percentage" again or not allow user to leave input field empty.